# How to rename many files (found with glob) from lower to the upper case without changing the extension?

Tags: linux, bash

I used:

```
rename 's/a-z/A-Z' *.txt
```

However, this command changes the register of the file extension as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think you mean this,

```
rename 's/([a-z])(?=.*?\.txt$)/\U$1/g' *.txt
```